# Pandas value counts aggregated by state

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

given this sample dataframe:

```
                med_1        med_2         Med_3    
   Pennsylvania OTC          Prescription   NaN 
   Maryland     Prescription OTC            Prescription
   Florida      Prescription OTC            NaN 
   Maryland     Nan          OTC            Prescription   
   Pennsylvania OTC          OTC            OTC
```

I know that value_counts() does not work on a groupby object, so I reviewed several answers on SO and none quite fit to get the following resulting df getting the total of Prescription and OTC summed by state.

```
State           Prescription OTC
Pennsylvania    1            4
Maryland        3            2
Florida         1            1
```

I am certain, as in certain like the sun is going to rise tomorrow, that I am missing something simple, but have spent a few hours wrangling and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `stack` and `unstack` + `value_counts`

```
out = df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack()
Out[121]: 
              OTC  Prescription
Florida       1.0           1.0
Maryland      2.0           3.0
Pennsylvania  4.0           1.0
```

Comment: Seriously, @BEN_YO that was dead on.  When are you teaching groupby next in a youtube video?  Sign me up.

Comment: @JohnTaylor yw ~ happy coding :-)